# Can't retrieve body params from PUT endpoint using formdata

Tags: plugin-development, rest-api, endpoints

I have one endpoint to create players, which is a PUT request to a certain route. While I was sending parameters via JSON, it was working fine, but now I need to upload a picture with data, so I switched to formdata format.

This is the function running in the endpoint:

```php
    public function put(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {

        ['foto' => $file] = $request->get_file_params();

        if (!empty($file)) {
            if (!function_exists('media_handle_upload')) {
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
                require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
            }

            $attachmentId = media_handle_upload('foto', 0);
        }

        //Recebe os dados
        $genero = $request['genero'];
        $nome = $request['nome'];
        $apelido = $request['apelido'];
        $data_nascimento = $request['data-nascimento'];
        $turma = $request['class_id'];
        $avatar = $request['avatar'];
        $id_parent = $request['user_id'];

        //Criar player
        $playerId = wp_insert_post([
            'post_type' => 'player'
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_title' => '',
            'post_author' => $id_parent,
            'meta_input' => [
                'genero' => $genero,
                'nome' => $nome,
                'apelido' => $apelido,
                'data-nascimento' => $data_nascimento,
                'avatar' => $avatar,
            ]
        ]);

        if (is_wp_error($playerId)) {
            return $this->error([
                'status' => 'error',
                'message' => 'Não foi possível criar o jogador'
            ]);
        }

        // ...
        return $this->response([
            'status' => 'success',
            'message' => 'player cadastrado',
            'id' => $playerId,
            // next row is added for testing purpose
            'body_params' => $request->get_body_params(),

        ], 201);
    }
```

This runs in `rest_api_init` hook:

```php
// ...
        register_rest_route("zw/v1", "players", [
                    'methods' => "PUT",
                    'callback' => [$playersApi, "put"],
                    'permission_callback' => [$playersApi, 'permissionCallback']
                ]);
```

When I use `PUT` method, `body_params` returns as empty array. Switching to `POST` method it works as expected. But I would like to keep semantics of the API, so what do I have to do to make `PUT` request read the body as formdata?

Comment: Can you include the endpoint/route registration that you're using with this callback? Internally the REST API considers POST PUT and PATCH to all be alias' of each other to be handled the same way  ( https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/06ab86cee6626a928d899fe208bcb8c98af2808b/wp-includes/rest-api/class-wp-rest-server.php#L33-L39 )

Comment: Looks like put method is not supported in forms, see eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form if thats how you use it.

Comment: I would note that after searching the WP codebase i can see no evidence of special handling of `PUT`, _however PUT doesn't mean what you think it means_, your endpoint doesn't fit the semantics of a `PUT` request anyway because `PUT` requests are an instruction to the server to take a given filepath that the server has access to and _put_ it on the server, it's not the same as uploading the file, and you wouldn't be providing other parameters anyway. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php

Comment: @TomJNowell I updated my post with the route registration

Comment: @TomJNowell about semantics, all I want is to keep standards that are already applied in the project, and having this one single case that is not compliant to everything else is annoying to me. I actually did change it to `POST` but I want to know why this happens.

Comment: your project is already non-compliant if you're trying to send these kind of requests as `PUT` requests. See my answer for why there are no body parameters

Comment: @birgire interesting. This is valid for HTML forms as well as using something like postman?

Comment: It is very possibly your tooling might be being "unhelpfully helpful" and wrapping it in a `POST`, dropping your parameters, or that it's sending non-compliant HTTP requests in hopes the other end will read them anyway, though I'm not sure what such a request would look like

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***This is because `PUT` requests don't have body parameters, that's not how `PUT` works**. `PUT` doesn't quite do what you thought it did, and can only be used to upload a file from a client.*

Your endpoint is incompatible with `PUT` as a request type because you're providing parameters as key value pairs, and that is not possible with `PUT`:

> According to the HTML standard, you can not. The only valid values for the method attribute are get and post, corresponding to the GET and POST HTTP methods.  is invalid HTML and will be treated like , i.e. send a GET request.

Likewise:

> XHTML 1.x forms only support GET and POST. GET and POST are the only allowed values for the "method" attribute.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-method
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054165/using-put-method-in-html-form

---

As for WordPress, it doesn't handle `PUT` and treats it as an alias of `POST` along with `PATCH`, so while its handling is technically correct, it's only by accident.

Now this doesn't prevent PHP from using it as a file upload mechanism, but that is the only thing it can be used for:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.put-method.php